# Suddenly getting 'Clear Read-Only Status' in Pycharm out of no where and I cant' change anything?? On Linux

Tags: pycharm

My Pycharm has been linked to my remote repository for the longest time.

But all of a sudden when I try to change something in one of my repos in Pycharm I get the error:

```
Clear Read-Only Status
```

ANd when I try to change the status I get:

```
Failed to change read-only status for the following files:
```

I've looked around for a few posts but nothing worked.

ANy ideas?

I noticed this when I did a `git pull` from my remote repo, and it pulled down in my local file system but didn't pull into pycharm, which is so weird. Then when I tried to change things in Pycharm I got the above error.

Answer (score 0):

## check your permissions for the file

make sure that read and write permissions are given to the file *'path-to-your-directory'*/.idea/workspace.xml
i had the same problem and solved it with this command:

```
    # chmod a+rw 'path-to-your-directory'/.idea/workspace.xml
```

this works for linux/mac, for windows visit this website https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-files-and-folders-permissions-in-windows-10